# OCMock/OCMVerify - Expression result unused

Tags: ios, xcode, xctest, ocmock

Calls like the following don't compile because of `Expression result unused` warning/error:

```
id object = [Foo new];
id mockObject = OCMPartialMock(object);
...
OCMExpect([mockObject doTheThing]);
...
OCMVerify(mockObject);
```

Tested on Xcode 12 GM:

```
$ clang -v
Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode_12_GM.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `OCMVerify(...)` with `OCMVerifyAll(...)`.

`OCMVerify(...)` is to verify after calls after running while `OCMVerifyAll(...)` is to verify expectations declared before running.

```
id object = [Foo new];
id mockObject = OCMPartialMock(object);
...
OCMExpect([mockObject doTheThing]);
...
OCMVerifyAll(mockObject);
```